# Is it possible to extract fonts from client side JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, pdf, pdf.js

I have tried using PDF.js, traced its code and find it insert CSS rule with font data to make the characters drawn to canvas display properly. But if I do the same I wasn't able to get the same result, I can't figure out why, can just guess it works only when characters are drawn one by one but not as normal text in HTML. Anyone know if it is possible to extract fonts from PDF solely from client side JavaScript? Thanks.

Comment: "Anyone know if it is possible to extract fonts from PDF solely from client side JavaScript?" Yes, definitely possible, though are you only asking about PDF.js? Or you are open to other client side solutions? Also, why is extracting the fonts important? What do you do with the extracted fonts?

Comment: Hi @Ryan , not just PDF.js, but it seems the only library that I found possible so far. I'm open to all JavaScript client side solutions. I want to use the extracted fonts directly in HTML so I can display the texts as extracted from the PDF document, but not via drawing using HTML5 Canvas. Thanks.